# How to match all lines that have two words that are not the same?

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible to use a Regex to match all lines that have 2 words that are not the same ?

I do understand that I can use `\d+: ([,\w]+ )\1|(.+)/gm`
This is where you capture the lines with the same word
Then capture everything else
Then you run the function to only do something with group 2
But is there a way to only match the lines that are not the same

1: 43,186 43,186 
2: 296,531 296,531 
3: 108086 108086 
4: abcdef abcdef 
`5: Capture This` 
6: 497,802 497,802 
`7: 200,062 300,062` 
`8: Not Same` 
`9: 202232 252232` 
10: 4,324,452 4,324,452

Example:

```js
let string = `
1: 43,186 43,186 
2: 296,531 296,531 
3: 108086 108086 
4: abcdef abcdef 
5: Capture This 
6: 497,802 497,802 
7: 200,062 300,062 
8: Not Same 
9: 202232 252232 
10: 4,324,452 4,324,452 `;

let magicalRegex = /\d+: (This One) (Does not match this one)/gm;

string.replace(magicalRegex, matched=>{
  /*These are the matches I found master*/
`
5: Capture This
7: 200,062 300,062
8: Not Same
9: 202232 252232
`
/*Run some special code*/
/*Return matched*/
});
```

`First`   `Second`      `Third`
`isNum:` `Anything`  `Must Match Second`

Comment: Maybe just a negative lookahead would work for you? Something like `^\d+: (\S+) (?!\1)\S+$` maybe?

Comment: Can you please clarify if the `Third` column can contain whitespaces? Does [this](https://regex101.com/r/omFVJs/1) work for you? If there can be whitespaces, I guess `^\d+:\s+(\S+)\s+(?!\1$)\S.*` [will be](https://regex101.com/r/omFVJs/2) a better solution.

Comment: Hi Monwell, could you please provide feedback so that we could help better?

Comment: Hey guys, this was the answer I was looking for `\d+: (\S+) (?!\1)\S+` this is from the first comment on the post. It does exactly what the question asked.

Comment: All the answers here are great answers to the probable… but I'm a simple man… I like simple equations. The shorter the better.

Comment: In my opinion, the solution should meet the original requirements. Shorter regexps tend to be "evil" regexps, compare [`^(\w+\s?)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/rs1FMt/1/) and the efficient [`^\w+(?:\s\w+)*\s?$`](https://regex101.com/r/rs1FMt/2) that do the same thing, but the first one is awfully slow and drains all computational power with even short (non-matching) strings. At any rate, please consider accepting an answer that works best for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `/^\d+:\s+(\S+)\s+(?!\1$)\S+$/gm` regex to extract the matches and then simply join the items, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/omFVJs/1) and the JavaScript demo below:

```js
let string = `1: 43,186 43,186
2: 296,531 296,531
3: 108086 108086
4: abcdef abcdef
5: Capture This
6: 497,802 497,802
7: 200,062 300,062
8: Not Same
9: 202232 252232
10: 4,324,452 4,324,452`;

let magicalRegex = /^\d+:\s+(\S+)\s+(?!\1$)\S+$/gm;

console.log( string.match(magicalRegex).join("\n") )
```

The `^\d+:\s+(\S+)\s+(?!\1$)\S+$` regex matches

- `^` - start of line
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `:` - a colon
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(\S+)` - Group 1: one or more non-whitespace chars
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?!\1$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there there is a Group 1 value immediately on the right till end of string
- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars
- `$` - end of line.

Answer (score 2):

For the OP's use case and requirements a simple regex which matches and [captures](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups) a non whitespace (sequence) separated by a whitespace (sequence) additionally needs to ensure the uniqueness of each new-line content via a [backreference](https://javascript.info/regexp-backreferences#backreference-by-number-n) used within a [negative lookahead](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#negative-lookahead) ... [`/^(\S+)\s+(?!\1).*/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/UpiqpM/1/) ...

```js
console.log(
`43,186 43,186
296,531 296,531
108086 108086
abcdef abcdef
Capture This
497,802 497,802
200,062 300,062
Not Same
202232 252232
4,324,452 4,324,452`.match(/^(\S+)\s+(?!\1).*/gm)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

And in order to fully match the OP's example code one has to refine the 1st regex from `/^(\S+)\s+(?!\1).*/gm` to [`/^(?:\d+\:\s*)(\S+)\s+(?!\1).*/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/UpiqpM/2) adding `(?:\d+\:\s*)` to the former which does match the digit-colon-whitespace pattern in the beginning of each new-line ...

```js
console.log(
`1: 43,186 43,186 
2: 296,531 296,531 
3: 108086 108086 
4: abcdef abcdef 
5: Capture This 
6: 497,802 497,802 
7: 200,062 300,062 
8: Not Same 
9: 202232 252232 
10: 4,324,452 4,324,452`.match(/^(?:\d+\:\s*)(\S+)\s+(?!\1).*/gm).join('\n')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if I understood you correctly the regex would look something like this

```
string regex = @"^(\w+)\s(?:(?!\1).)*$";
```

Here is the fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0ueUKd
And checked here: https://www.regexpal.com/